# MySQL with JOINs and COUNT

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables as follows:

```
markers
--->id
--->name

markers_date
--->id
--->markers_id
--->date
--->date2
--->time

registration
--->schedule_id
```

Using the following query:

```
SELECT markers.name, markers_date.id, markers_date.markers_id, markers_date.date, markers_date.date2, markers_date.time, registration.schedule_id
FROM markers_date
JOIN markers ON markers_date.markers_id=markers.id
JOIN registration ON registration.schedule_id=markers_date.id
```

The above query outputs correctly, however, I'd like to have a count of how many records have the same "schedule_id" and place that column next to "schedule_id".  I have tried the below COUNT statement.  But, that gave me only 1 result with the total count of all records.  There currently there are two records that have the same "schedule_id"

```
SELECT markers.name, markers_date.id, markers_date.markers_id, markers_date.date, markers_date.date2, markers_date.time, registration.schedule_id, 
COUNT(registration.schedule_id=markers_date.id)
FROM markers_date
JOIN markers ON markers_date.markers_id=markers.id
JOIN registration ON registration.schedule_id=markers_date.id
```

Below screenshot is what it currently looks like without the

```
COUNT(registration.schedule_id=markers_date.id)
```

[image]

But the next screenshot is what I want to achieve with the count next to it, photoshop'd.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.  I've watched quite a bit of youtube tutorials on JOIN, INNER, OUTER, etc.  However, could not find any JOINs with COUNTs to assist on the output that I am looking for.

Comment: Use `COUNT(schedule_id)` and `GROUP BY` at the end for schedule id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work:

```
SELECT
    markers.name
    ,markers_date.id
    ,markers_date.markers_id
    ,markers_date.date
    ,markers_date.date2
    ,markers_date.time
    ,registration.schedule_id
    ,COUNT(registration.schedule_id) AS COUNT
FROM markers_date
    JOIN markers ON markers_date.markers_id=markers.id
    JOIN registration ON registration.schedule_id=markers_date.id
GROUP BY
    markers.name
    ,markers_date.id
    ,markers_date.markers_id
    ,markers_date.date
    ,markers_date.date2
    ,markers_date.time
    ,registration.schedule_id
```

Comment: Thank you Raphael and AT-2017 confirmed and worked perfectly.  Also, marked as answered.  Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

The below isn't tested but you can try it using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT markers.name, markers_date.id, markers_date.markers_id, markers_date.date, markers_date.date2, markers_date.time, registration.schedule_id, 
COUNT(registration.schedule_id) AS 'COUNT'
FROM markers_date
JOIN markers ON markers_date.markers_id=markers.id
JOIN registration ON registration.schedule_id=markers_date.id 
GROUP BY registration.schedule_id
```